# Insert tab character in textarea

Tags: angularjs, textarea

How do I insert a tab character (indent) inside a textarea using AngularJS?

I tried this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" ng-model="vm.text" ng-keydown="vm.handleTabKey($event)"></textarea>
```

With function `handleTabKey` being:

```
function handleTabKey(e) {
  if (e.which === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = e.target.selectionStart;
    var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
    vm.text = vm.text.substring(0, start) + '\t' + vm.text.substring(end);
    e.target.selectionStart = e.target.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
};
```

Although the tab character is inserted, the caret position is always at the end, despite the last line.

Another problem is that if I insert one or more new lines at the end, pressing tab will insert a tab at the end of the line before the new lines, as if ignoring them. In other words, `vm.text` doesn't contain those new lines until non-whitespace characters are entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ngModel will trim white space at the end unless you use `ng-trim="false"`.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2010

Regarding the cursor position, I think you need to target the element and use [.setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) instead.

**UPDATE**

Based on your JSFiddle, I was able to set the cursor position using this instead:

```
angular.element(e.target).val(vm.text.substring(0, start) + '\t' + vm.text.substring(end));
```

<s>Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7bee7nuc/2/</s>

**UPDATE 2**

The previous snippet couldn't insert consecutive tab characters. To do this, `vm.text` must be updated as well as the target element.

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7bee7nuc/3/

Comment: Thanks, that solved the second problem, but it didn't fix the first.

Comment: Try adding `e.stopPropagation();` to be sure no other event handler is being called after yours.

Comment: I tried `e.target.setSelectionRange(start + 1, start + 1)`  but it still didn't work. I even included `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-keyup instead? If you can reproduce in a JSFiddle I'd be happy to tinker with it.

Comment: You have to update `vm.text` or else inserting multiple tabs in series won't work. Change the fiddle to reflect that and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [my pen](http://codepen.io/zulns/pen/yeEejM), it could accept formatting text with tab or shift tab character on a single line or multiple line just like a text editor. It has no need to any other JS library.